# Слэш в регулярных выражениях, PHP

Tags: php

Почему это регулярное выражение пропускает `site.com` без слэша в конце?

```
if(!preg_match('|^(http(s)?://)?(www.)?site.com/*|i', $_POST['site'])) {
```

Мне нужно провести проверку на наличие слеша после доменного имени

Comment: Вы в конце поставили `/*`. т.е. знак `/` может и не быть там. Измените на `/+` или просто на `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте вместо `*` - `+`

`'^(http(s)?://)?(www.)?site.com/+'`

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будет `|^(http(s)?://)?(www\.)?site\.com/$|i`, что означает — после обязательного `/` ни чего идти не должно.

Так же не забывайте ставить обратный слеш `\` перед точками, иначе `http://site-com` тоже пройдёт проверку.